# Blank rows occuring despite use of NOT NULL and <> ''

Tags: postgresql, pandas, blank-line

I'm trying to remove *all* empty/blank cells from my table. However, I have some blank cells remaining even *after* I attempt to remove them with the aforementioned methods in the title.

I've tried `NOT NULL` and `<> ''`, likewise, I've tried `>0`. None of these seem to remove the blank cells. I'm not sure what other type it could be. The columns are `varchar` so it's hard to identify what it is.

Seemingly, nobody has encountered this, as I haven't been able to find any similar articles or issues. This table is an incredible mess as there are glaring inconsistencies everywhere.

The statement I am using:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column is NOT NULL AND column <> ''
```

Ideally, all of the blank cells would be gone so I could insure that my Pandas df is accurate.

My code in Python is locating about 2,000 "null" entries in the table:

```
def enumerate_null_data(df):
    #pandas doesn't support blank strings or None distinguishments with isnull/isna, so we replace those with np.NaN
    #a data type that is consistent with its archictecture/is handled properly
    df['rfid_sent'].replace(['', None], np.nan, inplace=True)
    df['rfid_received'].replace(['', None], np.nan, inplace=True)
    #dataframe that no longer contains the null values
    sent_null_removed = df.dropna(subset=['rfid_sent'])
    received_null_removed = df.dropna(subset=['rfid_received'])

    #create a dataframe that has all of the entries that were removed from sent_null_removed/received_null_removed
    #and count them (get the length of that dataframe)
    num_sent_null_removed = len(df[~df.index.isin(sent_null_removed.index)].index)
    num_received_null_removed = len(df[~df.index.isin(received_null_removed.index)].index)


    # dataframe containing only the values that were null/NA
    na_only = df[~df.index.isin(sent_null_removed.index) | ~df.index.isin(received_null_removed.index)]

    return (na_only, num_sent_null_removed, num_received_null_removed)
```

I honestly have no idea what else to try. Is there some "Empty" format I am missing here? Pandas recognized the blank cells as:
`''`, `Empty`, `None` and `np.nan`. 
Yes, the whole variety. :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem had to do with Pattern Recognition using Regex. Particularly, I attempted a large number of solutions that filtered out any form of erroneous data types that would dirty the data table. Unfortunately, the solution was not so simple.

However, the data (that I am anticipating/want to remain) is highly consistent in structure, and so I just used RegEx to filter out any such data entries that did not align with my expectations.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably spaces or other whitespace characters stored in the column. Try like this:

```
WHERE col IS NOT NULL AND NOT col ~ '^\s*$'
```